How to use pal.node.fun with nod.fun in prp decision tree diagram package for R
Currently, I'm working on a project where we desire the labels under the tree diagram to show the accuracy rate (I figured out how to calculate this using values given in the tree data frame).  I've been able to get the labels to produce properly using the nod.fun in prp package.  However, after hours trying, I continue to get errors when trying to change the color palette based on the result of the accuracy shown in the nod.fun label (and saved in the tree data frame under tree2$frame$accuracy).  The code is below for what I have so far (sorry I cannot share the actual data we use).
Advice from someone who knows how to use the prp package really well is appreciated!!!
Here is the current code (sorry I can't share the data).
#Decision tree 2 
tree2 = rpart(Year1GPAcategory~HSGPA+BestACTScore+Age+EssayExecutionScore, data=traindata_3.0, method = "class", cp=0.008, parms=list(split="gini"), minbucket=300)

#tree node accuracy calculation added to frame - to correctly color & label each node!
tree2$frame$accuracy <- as.numeric(round(((tree2$frame$n-tree2$frame$dev)/tree2$frame$n)*100,0))
#view(tree2$frame)

#plot the tree
nodelabel <- function(x,labs,digits, varlen){
  acc <- as.numeric(tree2$frame$accuracy) 
  paste0(labs, "\n\nAccuracy: ",acc,"%")}
rpart.plot(tree2, type=5, extra=2, under=TRUE, cex=0.6, 
           main="Decision Tree 2 Results Using 3.0 Year 1 GPA Split", cex.main=1.5,
           sub="Tree diagram resulting from a model using 4 variables: HS GPA, Best ACT, Age & Essay Execution", cex.sub=0.9,
           box.palette=c("#4c6888","#b9d9eb","#d6d2c4", "#D9C89E"), pal.node.fun=TRUE,
           node.fun=nodelabel)


The resulting tree looks like this:
tree diagram with proper labels
However, with the pal.node.fun=TRUE, it is supposed to find the first numeric value, yet no matter whether I include the accuracy number in or outside the paste function, it's not being used as a numerical value.  Therefore, I always get this error when trying to use the nod.fun as the determinate value for the box.palette colors (instead of the fitted values as default in tree diagrams).
pal.node.fun error
I'm also open to using other decision tree diagram packages/libraries, if those are easier to achieve the desired results.
